# Extract values that match another column of exact search

Tags: sql, r, pool

I have this table:

```
 miRNA   | Cluster
 miR-371 | 5
 miR-302 | 6
 miR-372 | 5
 miR-342 | 0
```

And this table:

```
miRNA   | Cancer Type | Expression | Cluster
miR-371 | A           | 3.53       | 5
miR-371 | B           | 3.23       | 5
miR-372 | A           | 3.66       | 5
miR-372 | B           | 3.23       | 5
miR-302 | A           | 3.65       | 6
miR-302 | B           | 3.62       | 6
miR-342 | A           | 3.61       | 0
miR-342 | B           | 3.64       | 0
 etc
```

The desired output (from searching for specifically miR-371) is just cluster 5 from table two to create this output:

```
miRNA   | Cancer Type | Expression | Cluster
miR-371 | A           | 3.53       | 5
miR-371 | B           | 3.23       | 5
miR-372 | A           | 3.66       | 5
miR-372 | B           | 3.23       | 5
```

How can I do this in SQL?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which table in your database has the `miRNA` associated to `Cancer Type` and `Expression`?

Comment: The second one that includes miR-302 and miR-342 but I just want this filtered down to Cluster 5 (if I search for miR-371 or 372)

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at your schema, but wouldn't you just want to do a `JOIN` with your `miRNAcancerExpression` table?

Comment: Hi, I've just updated it to simplify what I've asked and I've read that I could do a JOIN or Subquery but I'm not quite sure how to execute it with a specific search for just one miRNA (e.g. miR-371) to collect all Cluster 5 miRNAs.